# Displaying and sizing a grayscale from a QImage in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have been able to display an image in a label in Qt using something like the following:

```
transformPixels(0,0,1,imheight,imwidth,1);//sets unsigned char** imageData

unsigned char* fullCharArray = new unsigned char[imheight * imwidth];
     for (int i = 0 ; i < imheight ; i++)
         for (int j = 0 ; j < imwidth ; j++)
                fullCharArray[(i*imwidth)+j] = imageData[i][j];

QImage *qi = new QImage(fullCharArray, imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_RGB32);

ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*qi,Qt::AutoColor));
```

So fullCharArray is an array of unsigned chars that have been mapped from the 2D array imageData, in other words, it is imheight * imwidth bytes.

The problem is, it seems like only a portion of my image is showing in the label. The image is very large. I would like to display the full image, scaled down to fit in the label, with the aspect ratio preserved.

Also, that QImage format was the only one I could find that seemed to give me a close representation of the image I am wanting to display, is that what I should expect? I am only using one byte per pixel (unsigned char - values from 0 to 255), and it seems liek RGB32 doesnt make much sense for that data type, but none of the other ones displayed anything remotely correct

edit:
Following dan gallaghers advice, I implemented this code:

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(fullCharArray, imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
int labelWidth = ui->viewLabel->width();
int labelHeight = ui->viewLabel->height();

QImage small = qi->scaled(labelWidth, labelHeight,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(small,Qt::AutoColor));
```

But this causes my program to "unexpectedly finish" with code 0

Comment: According to the documentation QImage::Format_RGB32 seems to be 8bit/color + 8bit padding to make it 32bit for making working with it easier, so how doesn't that make sense for 8bit/color data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QImage` has a `scaled` member.  So you want to change your `setPixmap` call to something like:

```
QImage small = qi->scaled(labelWidth, labelHeight, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(small, Qt::AutoColor);
```

Note that `scaled` does not modify the original image `qi`; it returns a new `QImage` that is a scaled copy of the original.

Re-Edit:

To convert from 1-byte grayscale to 4-byte RGB grayscale:

```
 QImage qi = new QImage(imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
 for (int i = 0; i < imheight; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < imwidth; j++)
     {
         qi->setPixel(i, j, QRgb(imageData[i][j], imageData[i][j], imageData[i][j]));
     }
 }
```

Then scale `qi` and use the scaled copy as the pixmap for `viewLabel`.

Comment: I tried somethign like this before. It causes my program to unexpectedly finish. Any ideas?

Comment: It is probably something with the RGB32 format.  It looks like Qt is expecting 4 bytes per pixel in that format, and you only have 1.  You may need to multiply the size of your array by 4, then duplicate your value 3 times (with the first byte in every quartet set to 0) to get grayscale.  See my edit.

Comment: Well, that prevented it from crashing, but now most of my label is black, with a bar of distorted imagery along the top of the label.

Comment: Instead of using a secondary array (`fullCharArray`), you ought to try using `QImage::setPixel`.  You would initialize the `QImage` with the correct `imwidth` and `imheight`, then loop over your `imageData` array, but use `qi->setPixel(i, j, QRgb(imageData[i][j], imageData[i][j], imageData[i][j]))`.

Comment: The RGBA type in QImage requires the alpha channel to be > any of the values. Just set it to 0xff.

Comment: I tried this implementation, and I got what looked like a zoomed in view of a portion of the image. Im not sure what your comment is getting at Martin - we havent been using RGBA

Comment: Did you still scale the image after setting the pixel values?

Comment: finally got it working with your suggestion in the comments here - you should edit your answer with that.

Answer (score 6):

Qt doesn't support grayscale image construction directly. You need to use 8-bit indexed color image:

```
QImage * qi = new QImage(imageData, imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
for(int i=0;i<256;++i) {
    qi->setColor(i, qRgb(i,i,i));
}
```

Comment: +1 "Qt doesn't support grayscale image construction directly" - Thanks! Good information.

Answer (score 3):

I've also faced similar problem - QImage::scaled returned black images. The quick work-around which worked in my case was to convert QImage to QPixmap, scale and convert back then. Like this:

```
QImage resultImg = QPixmap::fromImage(image)
  .scaled( 400, 400, Qt::KeepAspectRatio )
  .toImage();
```

where "image" is the original image.
I was not aware of format-problem, before reading this thread - but indeed, my images are 1-Bit black-white.

Regards,
Valentin Heinitz