# Display grayscale image using Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have been trying to display a gray-scale image using Qt. The image data is loaded from a .txt file that contains 256x256 float data. There is no header involved for the image. I have tried the solution posted in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727625/displaying-and-sizing-a-grayscale-from-a-qimage-in-qt/4727757#4727757)

I used `QLabel` class to call `setPixmap` of my `uchar* image_data_array`. Even though I could get a Qt GUI window to open, but the window shows just blank screen.

imageLabel -> setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*myImage));

Comment: It is preferable to split the two questions you have into two **different** questions, so it would be easier to the people who answer to focus on each of them individually. It will also help other people in the future to access the relevant parts.

Comment: If you are asking 2 questions here, I agree with Shai. I would suggest that you make sure displaying an unaltered QPixmap in your QLabel works and then move on to altering it.

Answer (score 3):

```
QImage img = AImage;
if (!AImage.isNull())
{
    int pixels = img.width() * img.height();
    if (pixels*(int)sizeof(QRgb) <= img.byteCount())
    {
        QRgb *data = (QRgb *)img.bits();
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels; i++)
        {
            int val = qGray(data[i]);
            data[i] = qRgba(val, val, val, qAlpha(data[i]));
        }
    }
}
return img;
```

Use RGBA for good grayscale.

Answer (score 2):

How are you loading the QImage with the grey image data ?

QT doesn't have a greyscale image type, only a bilevel type. You can either create an RGB image with R=G=B=grey. Or more preferably use `QImage::Format_Indexed8` and create a colour table where each entry has the same value as the index. i.e.

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(data_ptr, width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
QVector<QRgb> my_table;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) my_table.push_back(qRgb(i,i,i));
qi->setColorTable(my_table);
```

Comment: The greyscale image data is first loaded from a 256x256 text file. Since I am loading the text data, I don't need to do setColorTable. How do you display the QImage?

Comment: As I said, QT doesn't have a greyscale format so you're going to have to do some work to make a suitable image. QImage::Format_Indexed8 is a palleted format so you do need to set a table to show what colour each index represents. You can display an image by many methods; using a QPixmap, making a custom widget, using a QGraphicsView, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In QT 5.9.1 there is an option to create a grayscale image:

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(data_ptr, width, height, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```