# bad quality, when rendering images from camera in qt4

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

My code:

```
camera = new RaspiCam_Cv();//raspbery pi library 

camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT,CV_8UC1); //this is monochrome 8 bit format
camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 960);
camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

while (1){
    camera->grab();//for linux
    unsigned char* buff = camera->getImageBufferData();

    QPixmap pic = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage( buff, camWidth_, camHeight_,  camWidth_ * 1, QImage::Format_Indexed8 ));
    label->setPixmap(pic);
}
```

The problem is bad quality! I found out that the problem happens when using `QImage`, when using `openCv Mat`, everything is good!

Same thing happens in other Qt based programs, like this one (same bad quality): https://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/

Here is a pic, where the problem is shown. ***there is a white page in front of the camera, so if all went as it should, you should see clean gray image***.

[image: photo of monitor]

Comment: Have you tried not to specify the number of bytes per line when creating your image? Like this: `QImage( buff, camWidth_, camHeight_, QImage::Format_Indexed8 )`

Comment: Yes, I have. this not the problem.. this happens in RGB as WELL, but in gray, this getting worse(you see the problem clearly). and as i said, i tried other qt apps, same problem! may it be qt bug? :(

Comment: @user3580937 take a snapshot directly from your computer and post the image into the question, not through a third party website.

Comment: can you post the code which works for cv::Mat version? .grab will maybe only capture the image, not decode it! It would suggest to grab+retrieve to a cv::Mat and use the Mat buffer to display in qt

Comment: I cant upload images here(10+ repo needed).

Comment: int main(int argc, char** argv){
    RaspiCam_Cv *camera = new RaspiCam_Cv();
 
 camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT , CV_8UC1) ; 
    camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 960);
    camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

   namedWindow("Output",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;
  camera.grab();
        camera.retrieve ( frame);
  
        imshow("Output", frame);

        if (waitKey(30) == 27)
        {
        cout << "Exit" << endl;
        break;
        }
    }
 camera->~RaspiCam_Cv();
    return 0;
}

Comment: "grab will maybe only capture the image, not decode it! " - no, it is not it, i have the raspicam source code , nothing decoded in the retrieve function. i did try to use  retrieve(), it is the same... ***it is not that i do not see the image at all***, i do see it, just in bad quality, a white page in front of the camera is the best way to show the quality problem.

Comment: can you try from your working Mat sample  to .grab an then create cv::Mat with camera->getImageBufferData(); as input data pointer? Tell me whether this works or doesnt work

Comment: @user3580937 on my desktop pc I could see the tinyPic image. So your problem is the pink and green line which are horizontal at 1/3 and 2/3 of the image? Maybe your image is in wrong format. Tutorials use RaspiCam in this way: 1. grab 2. retrieve to allocated data memory and give information about the color format. See for example http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40

Comment: void Private_Impl::retrieve ( unsigned char *data,RASPICAM_FORMAT type ) {
            if ( callback_data._buffData.size==0 ) return;
            if ( type!=RASPICAM_FORMAT_IGNORE ) {
                cerr<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<" :Private_Impl::retrieve type is not RASPICAM_FORMAT_IGNORE as it should be"<<endl;
            }
            memcpy ( data,callback_data._buffData.data,getImageTypeSize ( State.captureFtm ) );
        }

Comment: unsigned char *Private_Impl::getImageBufferData() const{
            return callback_data._buffData.data;
        }

Comment: void RaspiCam_Cv::retrieve ( cv::Mat& image ) {
        //here we go!
        image.create ( _impl->getHeight(),_impl->getWidth(),imgFormat );
        _impl->retrieve ( image.ptr<uchar> ( 0 ));
    }

Comment: as you can see nothing wrong using the getImageBufferData() method.. (it saves us time). and yes i did try using the  retrieve(), i am starting to think it is some qt4 and PI problem, i will try using qt5, and update here my findings..  (same code works well under windows os; well allmost the same, in windows I am using openCv as an api, to capture frames from my camera.

Comment: In Qt you use `Format_Indexed8` but you didnt set the color table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678093/display-grayscale-image-using-qt on how to create and set the color table for indexed8 format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided images look like the color depth is only 16 Bit.

For comparison, here's the provided captured image:

[image]

and here's the same image, transformed to 16 bit color space in IrfanView (without Floyd-Steinberg-Dithering).

[image]

In the comments we found out that the Raspberry Pi Output Buffer was set to 16 Bit. and setting it to 24 Bit helped.

But I can't explain why rendering the image on the pi with OpenCV's `cv::imshow` produced well looking images on the Monitor/TV...

Answer (score 1):

You are resizing the image using pixmap and label transformations, which are worse than the one of QImage. This is due to pixmap being optimized for display and not for anything else. The pixmap size should be the same of the label to avoid any further resizing.

```
QImage img =QImage( 
    buff, 
    camWidth_, 
    camHeight_,  
    camWidth_ * 1, 
    QImage::Format_Indexed8 ).scaled(label->size());
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

Comment: It does not change a thing.., I set the label to  const size. label->setFixedHeight(camera->getCamHeight());
label->setFixedWidth(camera->getCamWidth());  but the problem remains..

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it's too hard to share code in the comments.
Can you please test this code and tell me whether the result is good or bad?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    RaspiCam_Cv *camera = new RaspiCam_Cv(); 
    camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT , CV_8UC1) ; 
    camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 960); 
    camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720); 
    namedWindow("Output",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
    while (1) 
    { 
        Mat frame; 
        camera.grab(); 
        //camera.retrieve ( frame); 
        unsigned char* buff = camera->getImageBufferData();
        frame = cv::Mat(720, 960, CV_8UC1, buff);
        imshow("Output", frame); 
        if (waitKey(30) == 27) 
        { cout << "Exit" << endl; break; } 
    } 
    camera->~RaspiCam_Cv(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: when using openCV, everything fine! (yes this code give perfect results). i tried everything you suggested, nothing seems to work. I think you did not understand the problem, so i will upload 2 images, 1 good openCv image, and the other Qt bad one, there is a white page in front of the camera both cases, so i should get clear gray square. this is what i get when using openCv, but in Qt, i get odd circles, here is an image side by side.    http://i60.tinypic.com/208wgw2.png. sorry for not indenting (did not know how to before).

Comment: did you set the qt color table?

Comment: yes... (you can see this in the image)... i am trying qt5 right now, lets see how it goes..

Comment: I cant see the images on my mobile. please use picload.org . Did you try to capture to openCB, then convert to RGB and then display in Qt in RGB frmat? I think you don't understand how to systematically find error sources. Can you add sample code where you set the color table? please add those code samples (what you've tried) to your question text, not to comments.

Comment: Did you try to capture to openCB, then convert to RGB and then display "in Qt in RGB frmat?". yes i did. no meter what i try, it the same.. i will soon post my code, here is the image  http://pl.vc/1i09z.

Comment: is there a reason why you use 8UC3 type and different resolution in your openCV example than in your provided code? Can you use Qt methods to load an image from disk and try to display that?

Comment: can you please use cv::imwrite and qimage::save methods to save images to disk test whether those artifacts appear in the qimage or only in the rendering routine?

Comment: no reason for the different resolution(does not meter).  the 8uc3, was a mistake.. (it is colorful, should be 8uc1, both work fine in openCV). i will try what asked,saving images on disk. one more thing ***i also tried to work with the native openCv api to get the images from camera, and same problems accord as with the raspicam api, same code 1 to 1! works perfectly well in my windows8 machine+usb cam. the reason i work with raspicam api, is...

Comment: it has native support in monochrome format, 
in openCv i can capture only in RGB, i need the monochrome, for performance.. 
so if same code works under windows, it maybe not my bug after all...
anyway i will try what you asked + i will give qt5 a try..

Comment: from documentation, rendering a QImage might reduce the color-space if the monitor cant handle 24 or 32 bit colors. So maybe your monitor isnt set up correctly in Ubuntu (unlikely because OpenCV rendering works) or maybe Qt THINKS that your monitor can't handle 24 bit colors. Not sure how Qt determines the rendering capabilities... But it will be really important to know whether savin QImage to file gives good or bad result :) Loading a (color) image from file directly to a QLabel might be another hint.

Comment: well... it saves bad image to disk... any ideas? :)

Comment: o!!!! somthing very strange! this image seems bad on pi! but it is ok on my windows machine!!! WTFFF??!??!?!?!

Comment: Do they use the same monitor? Did you use the `Pi` for the OpenCV tests at all?

Comment: yes! same monitor! on my pi it looks like crap. on my laptop(same tv monitor), it looks like it should! to be clear 100% i save the images as png, open this png on pi, it looks bad, copy same image to my windows machine, and it looks fine on same monitor, i have seen strange thing.. but nothing like this...

Comment: and the `cv::Mat` tests were performed on the `pi`? If not, please check your monitor setting in unbuntu on the `pi`, probably it won't render 24 bit colors to output because it doesnt know about the monitor's capabilities?!? Do you use the analog pi output or hdmi pi output?

Comment: not sure whether this is still an issue: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/41

Comment: i am thinking it has something to do with bad file encoding after-all, i guess windows know how to overcome this, and linux sticks to standard. the only question is, where is my mistake??? maybe you can look at the file it self? here is the image. http://tinyurl.com/ogo9ukm

Comment: the CV looks good on pi! i use HDMI. so maybe it is encoding thing after all? maybe windows knows how to handle this png, and linux does not? could this be??,

Comment: if you save the OpenCV Mat with `cv::imwrite` to a `png`, what's the result?

Comment: I changed your provided image to 16 Bit color with IrfanView (without using dithering). The result looks like: https://picload.org/image/prcaaro/testpiimage_16bit.png So maybe OpenCV uses floyd-steinberg-dithering for rendering in 16 bit color depth but Qt doesn't? But then, the cv::imrwite result would be looking bad on your pi image viewer, too, I guess. If it is some decoding problem, try saving to `.bmp` which doesnt need to be decoded!

Comment: i will try saving Mat as png. and the Qimage as bmp... if it is an encoding problem.. what do i do? :) well, in few minutes i will post my findings..

Comment: ok! so the saved mat file indeed looks bad! (as you said). but the odd thing is, that even if i save Qimage as "BMP", it still looks bad...

Comment: from raspicam example this is how they save buffer to file(ppm format).  std::ofstream outFile ( "raspicam_image.ppm",std::ios::binary );
    outFile<<"P6\n"<<Camera.getWidth() <<" "<<Camera.getHeight() <<" 255\n";
    outFile.write ( ( char* ) data, Camera.getImageTypeSize ( raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_RGB )

Comment: does such a .ppm image look better? I think your image viewer doesnt render the image as good as openCV does.Csn you try to find out the output buffer depth of your pi? I bet it is 16 bit!

Comment: sorry )) i have lost you... " try to find out the output buffer depth of your pi" what do you mean? so you are saying there is nothing i can do :(

Comment: no, you can set the pi output buffer depth to 24 or 32 bit, but I guess it isnt. Instead it probably is set to 16 bit so your image quality is reduced during rendering.

Comment: how do i check this? ps **thank you so much!!** i was getting crazy over this thing for 2 days! (i mean really 2 days )))

Comment: thank you! you were correct, it was 16 bit! ones i set it to 24, it fixed the problem! http://www.viclog.com/entry/running-xubuntu-with-xfce-4-12-on-an-overclocked-rpi-2

Comment: my English is so-so.. )) it took me some time to understand what is "buffer depth" ))), if my English were better, i would save us both about 2 hours :)

Comment: I've added another answer so that anyone else who encounters the same problem will find an answer without reading all the comments :)