# Load a .raw image in QT

Tags: c++, image, qt

I want to load some *.raw* grey-scale images in QT. I know how can I load images in QT, But my problem is that I want to have the matrix representation of the image too. Since my image is grey-scale I want to have it as a matrix with elements between 0 and 255. I have done similar thing before but I used *OpenGL*. I was wondering if I could do the same just with QT.

My second problem is showing this matrix as an image. Since I want to manipulate the matrix to compress my image I need a way to show my matrix again as a picture. Is this possible with QT alone? or I should use other tools?

Comment: Use `QImage`? Read its docs carefully, at least. Anyway, your question is rather unclear to me... Try something (after reading the docs), then ask a more specific question (or edit this one).

Comment: IIRC QImage doesn't support greyscale data so you might need to set the pixels manually. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678093/display-grayscale-image-using-qt

Comment: When you say "a .raw image" which format do you mean specifically?

Comment: @MrEricSir Check (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format). Raw images are easier to process.

Comment: @bido Raw camera images aren't so much "easier to process" as they haven't been processed at all -- they're data straight out of the camera's sensor. It's sort of analogous to undeveloped film, except every camera uses a different data format. Qt (or any other toolkit that I'm aware of) doesn't provide support for decoding these files. There's various 3rd party libraries like libraw and dcraw that can do this for you, but you they may or may not support your specific camera.