# how to display an image with integer array data in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have already extracted RGB data from a QImage with functions:

`QImage::red()`, `QImage::green()`, `QImage::blue()`.

After converting the data into YUV, I want to display three images to show Y, U and V values.

My question is: is there a way to construct a QImage with an integer array, to display greyscale image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678093/display-grayscale-image-using-qt

Comment: @kernel thanks, I didn't see that post before..